# mfinderというソフトの実行に関して

Tags: windows

プログラミングに直接関わるかは微妙なのですが質問させていただきます。
有向ネットワークの解析をするためにUriAlonさんが作ったmfinder（http://www.weizmann.ac.il/mcb/UriAlon/download/network-motif-software）というソフトを使いたいのですが、うまくいきません。

環境：Windows7 64bit
マニュアルにしたがって以下のような操作をしました。
ーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーー
mfinder1.21.zipをダウンロード、解凍、c直下に保存
コマンドプロンプトでmfinder1.2.exeがあるディレクトリまで移動（dirコマンドで確認）
コマンド　”mfinder network_exmp.txt”実行　      →失敗
コマンド　”mfinder1.2 network_exmp.txt”実行　　　→失敗
コマンド　”mfinder1.2.exe network_exmp.txt”実行　→失敗
ーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーー
全て”mfinder1.2は内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド操作可能なプログラムまたはバッチファイルとして認識されていません”と実行できません。

知識不足でちゃんとした質問になっているか不安ですが、是非皆さんの力をお貸しください。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

mfinder1.2.zip（サイト上は1.21と書かれていますが）をダウンロードして試してみました。

`mfinder1.2` というフォルダごと圧縮されていたので、私はこれを `R:\` に展開しました。つまり `R:\mfinder1.2\mfinder1.2.exe` が存在することになります。

```
R:\> cd mfinder1.2

R:\mfinder1.2> dir
（略）
2015/07/08  14:49    <DIR>          .
2015/07/08  14:49    <DIR>          ..
2005/08/29  11:08         1,622,016 mfinder1.2.exe
2005/08/24  16:16           866,710 mfinderManual.pdf
2002/10/22  16:57            91,190 motifDictionary.pdf
2003/10/13  13:55               157 network_exmp.txt
2003/10/13  14:08             1,861 output_exmp.txt
2005/08/24  16:19             4,480 README.txt
（略）

R:\mfinder1.2> mfinder1.2 network_exmp.txt
mfinder Version 1.20
（略）
```

`操作可能なプログラムまたはバッチファイルとして～` はファイルが見つからない時に表示されますから、ディレクトリの移動が正しく行えているか、ファイル名を打ち間違えていないか、今一度確認してみてください。

なお、ディレクトリの移動が正しく行えているのであれば、最初の一文字 `m` だけ入力して <kbd>Tab</kbd> キーを押すことで `mfinder1.2.exe` （拡張子も含む）が補完されると思います。

Comment: お返事ありがとうございます。
c:\mfinder1.2>mfinder1.2 dir
（略）
2015/07/09 <DIR> mfinder1.2
（略）
c:\mfinder1.2>mfinder1.2 network_exmp.exmp.txt
’mfinder1.2'は内部コマンドまた・・・・

という具合で。教えていただいたようTABキーでの補完はできました。
ですが依然とし内部コマンド・・・・と表示されています。

Comment: `2015/07/09 <DIR> mfinder1.2` と表示されるなら、あなたがいるのは `mfinder1.2.exe` の**一つ上**のディレクトリではありませんか？回答に載せたdirコマンドの出力例をすこし書き足したので、比べてみてください。

Comment: なんと・・・　ディレクトリがひとつ上でした。
初歩的ミスでお手を煩わしてすみませんでした。
お答えいただき本当にありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1):

> mfinder1.2 network_exmp.txt

現在の階層を意識せずに実行したいのであれば環境変数を設定すると良いと思います。

以降は蛇足な気もしますが念のため記載しておきます。

環境変数の設定方法

スタート -> コントロールパネル -> システム -> システムの詳細設定 -> 環境変数

「ユーザ環境変数」 or 「システム環境変数」にパスを追加
※自分のユーザのみに設定したいのであれば「ユーザ環境変数」

個人的にはこんな感じで新規で変数を作成する方が好きです。

・変数を追加する
新規 -> 変数名 mfinder1.2 変数値 mfinder1.2へのパス（.exeのあるフォルダまで）

・Pathに追加する
「Path」を選択して「編集」（無ければ「新規」）-> 作成した変数を追加（%mfinder1.2%）OK -> OK
！Pathの変数値に他のパスが書いてある場合は「;」で区切る

コマンドプロンプトを再起動して「mfinder1.2 -h」と入力して「Usage：～」と出力されたらOK
※1:「mfinder1.2」は使用している.exeの名前を指定してください。

※2:「内部コマンド～」のエラーが出たら
・cmd.exeを管理者で実行
・一回ログオフ
・一回再起動
とか試すと上手くいく（環境変数が反映される）と思います。